# FormGroup validation after redirect

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which looks like that:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
        items: new FormArray([])
      })
```

Where 'items' containing few FormControls. Every control's validators are changes depending on the User interactions with the form. After the form is submitted program saves it in dataService. However the User can turn back to edit the values of the form. So I need to recreate the form and use saved data from dataService.
Here is how I am doing it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if((this.dataService.orderForm.controls['items'] as FormArray).length > 0){
      this.form = this.dataService.orderForm
    } else {
      this.form = new FormGroup({
        items: new FormArray([])
      })
      this.addItem()
    }
  }
```

This code is able to rebuild the form that I need, but the problem is that submitting button is disabled (because it has a condition `[disabled]="!form.valid"`). However, if I write `console.log(this.form.valid)` after the assignment it writes that actually the form is valid. What's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: What are you setting to this.dataService.orderForm when you are submitting ?

Comment: This will help me understand if you are setting the json or the form itself

Comment: Where do you print the console?

Comment: @Akhil this.dataService.orderForm = this.form

Comment: @ShaharShokrani , after this piece of code in ngOnInit:
this.form = this.dataService.orderForm

Comment: Ok, let me furnish an answer with explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that we need to add functions that are changing Validators depending on the value that was saved. To do so we need to use this piece of code in ngOnInit after assign new Form to saved form from dataService:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        let i = 0
        for (let item of this.form.get('items')['controls']) {
          this.modelSelectChanged(i, this.form.value.items[i].modelSelect, this.form.value.items[i].articleSelect)
          i++
        }
```

In this way, the function will start 1ms after the dom will be created and values can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

While submitting set:

`this.dataService.orderForm = this.form.value;`

Now, in OnInIt, write :

`this.form.setValue(this.dataService.orderForm);`

Please comment if you need further information

Comment: So how dataService.orderForm should look like then? 
Before it was : 

orderForm = new FormGroup({
    items: new FormArray([])
  })

Comment: It will look like a JSON with key being your formControlName and value being your value for that corresponding control

Comment: I mean this :: orderForm = new FormGroup({ items: new FormArray([]) }) will look as it is but this.orderForm.value will look like a JSON

Comment: unfortunately the same problem, the problem is that the program doesn't understand that it should change the Validator which may be different from 'basic'. When the User manually changes the value the submit button activates. So is there any way to set the value of the input in ngOnInit as it is user sets it?

Comment: Ok.. After writing this.form.setValue(this.dataService.orderForm); 

Write :: this.form.updateValueAndValidity();

Comment: I will not help, I have already tried it. The thing is that I have set all Controls as required by default. But, after changing some inputs they can become unrequired here is an example:
`factoryChanged(ind: number) {
 if (this.form.value.items[ind].factorySelect === 'COP') {
 let idWithInd = 'articleSelect2' + ind
 document.getElementById(idWithInd).setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 this.form.get(`items.${ind}.articleSelect2`).setValue('')
 this.form.get(`items.${ind}.articleSelect2`).setErrors(null)
}
}`
So I have to imitate '(change)' event on the inputs to trigger functions